# Shared_Ptr pointing to correct object but not being assigned

Tags: c++, linked-list, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I am learning about smart pointers and tried implementing in a linked list.the code of the node, List and main files are as follows:

Node.h

```
 #pragma once
 #include <memory>

class Node {
    int data;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> next;

public:
    Node(int);
    int getValue();
    void setValue(int);
    std::shared_ptr<Node> Next();
};
```

Node.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Node.h"

Node::Node(int value) : data(value){}

int Node::getValue(){
    return data;
}

void Node::setValue(int value){
    data = value;
}

std::shared_ptr<Node> Node::Next(){
    return next;
}
```

List.h

```
class List{
    std::shared_ptr<Node> head;
    public:
        //List();
        bool isEmpty();
        void insertNode(int value);
        void printList();

};
```

List.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "List.h"
#include <iostream>

bool List::isEmpty(){
    return (head == nullptr) ? true : false;
}

void List::insertNode(int value){

    Node newNode(value);
    if (isEmpty()){
        head = std::make_shared<Node>(newNode);
    }

    else{
        newNode.Next()=head; //Problem here
        head = std::make_shared<Node>(newNode);
    }
}
void List::printList(){
    while (head->Next() != nullptr){
        std::cout << head->getValue();
    }
    std::cout << head->getValue();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "List.h"
#include <iostream>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    List newSingleList;
    if (newSingleList.isEmpty())
        std::cout << "The list is curently empty\n";
    newSingleList.insertNode(10);
    newSingleList.insertNode(20);
    newSingleList.printList();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the value in the List.cpp file at "the commented line"
the debugger shows that even after the assignment the value is empty and the 
node actually points to nothing. then the head in the next line is set to the
new node which then basically points to a different memory address without linking to the previous Node .

Why is this ? what am I missing ?

Here is the debugger snapshot: as said the next points to empty after stepover the breakpoint. according to the code the statement at the breakpoint must assign the next pointer to the previous head/node.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yaybpukacx53fq1/Screenshot%202015-03-08%2011.33.08.png?dl=0

Comment: Don't see the new smart pointers as a replacement for normal pointers, instead you should look at them from a resource ownership perspective. Can a resource have only one owner? Then use `std::unique_ptr`. Can a resource be shared? Then use `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: A couple of other points: The result of the expression `head == nullptr` *is* already a boolean `true` or `false` value. And your `printList` function will run forever printing the same node value over and over.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a shared pointer problem at all. Based on your usage, I think `Next` is supposed to be returning a *reference* to `next`, but instead you're returning a copy.

(if `Next` is *supposed* to return a copy, then you can't use `Next` at all to modify the value of `next`, so you'll have to do that another way)

Answer (score 0):

#### Introduction

The problem is that you are assigning to a temporary returned by `std::shared_ptr<Node> Node::Next ()`, ie. you are **not** updating the data-member `next` in `newNode` on the following line:

```
newNode.Next () = head;
```

The above is semantically equivalent to the below, because of how `Node::Next` is declared (you are returning a copy - and not a reference to the *data-member*):

```
{
  auto __temp = newNode.Next ();
       __temp = head;
}
```

---

#### How do I fix it?

Instead of returning a *copy* of `next` from `Node::Next`, make it return a *reference* to the *data-member*:

```
class Node {
    int data;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> next;

public:
    Node(int);
    int getValue();
    void setValue(int);
    std::shared_ptr<Node>& Next();
};
```

```
std::shared_ptr<Node>& Node::Next(){
    return next;
}
```